# this.state not populating fields in editProfile.component

Tags: reactjs, axios, state

Newbie here. Basic question I know. I have made a 'newProfile' component using pretty much the same mechanics as this and it's working! Now I need an editProfile component that updates the Profile form with props from the database using params.id. The URL shows the .id piece is working when I click 'edit' on a profile in a profileList component that is also working. This code is not getting errors, but it is not showing state for each of the fields.

What am I missing?

`

```
export default class EditProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangeFirst = this.onChangeFirst.bind(this);
    this.onChangeLast = this.onChangeLast.bind(this);
    this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDob = this.onChangeDob.bind(this);
    this.onChangeLocation = this.onChangeLocation.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      first: '',
      last: '',
      email: '',
      password:'',
      dob:'',
      location:'',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/profiles/'+this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          username: response.data.username,
          first: response.data.first,
          last: response.data.last,
          email: response.data.email,
          password: response.data.password,
          dob: response.data.dob,
          location: response.data.location
        })   
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
      
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({
            users: response.data.map(user => user.username),
          })
        }  
      })
    
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  onChangeProfilePic(e) {
    this.setState({
      profilePic: e.target.value
    });
  }  
    onChangeUsername(e) {
      this.setState({
        username: e.target.value
      });
    }
    onChangeFirst(e) {
      this.setState({
        first: e.target.value
      });
    }
    onChangeLast(e) {
      this.setState({
        last: e.target.value
      });
    }
    onChangeEmail(e) {
      this.setState({
        email: e.target.value
      });
    }
    onChangePassword(e) {
      this.setState({
        password: e.target.value
      });
    }
    onChangeDob(e) {
      this.setState({
        dob: e.target.value
      });
    } onChangeLocation(e) {
      this.setState({
        location: e.target.value
      });
    }
    
    onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

    
      const profile = {
        username: this.state.username,
        first: this.state.first,
        last: this.state.last,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        dob: this.state.dob,
        location: this.state.location,
      }

      console.log(profile);

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/profiles/update'+this.props.match.params.id, profile)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        window.location = '/';
    }

    render() {
      return (
      <div>
        <h3>Edit Profile
        </h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group"> 
            <label>Username: 
            </label>
              <input  
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                  />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group"> 
            <label>First Name: 
            </label>
              <input  
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.first}
                  onChange={this.onChangeFirst}
                  />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group"> 
            <label>Last Name: 
            </label>
              <input  
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.last}
                  onChange={this.onChangeLast}
                  />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email: 
              </label>
              <input 
                  type="text" 
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
                  />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password: 
            </label>
              <input 
                  type="text" 
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                  />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )}
}
```

`

Here is the error I'm getting in the console.

react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
at input
at div
at form
at div
at CreateProfile (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:194:5)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44214:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44678:5)
at div
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44609:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42779:5)
at App

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what those errors are the code is returning. You can use react dev tools plugin to debug(see) the state value(state for each of the fields)

Comment: @AbdelghanyMh thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my post with the error